# DirectX 10 IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer Multithread CTD Error

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, directx-10

I'm trying to create a multi-threaded program where all of the rendering is done on the primary thread while the message handling (and window creation) is done on a secondary thread.  The following line of code `SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D10Texture2D), (void**)&back_buffer);` in the initialization function produces an access violation error (0xc0000005) when the initialization function is placed on the main thread.

How can I fix this error without placing the initialization function on the secondary thread?

EDIT:  I have posted all of the relevant code [here](https://github.com/TChapman500/Test-Renderer/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: It is not possible to guess what exactly went wrong unless you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least the initialization part. The approach with separate rendering thread can work (it is even preferred), however extra care should be taken to deal with possible deadlocks and to prevent concurrent calls to DXGI methods.

Comment: I've put a link to a GitHub repository containing all of the relevant code.

Comment: Your code lacks error handling. You must inspect all the HRESULT return values and check that DX calls actually succeeded.

Comment: Error-handling proved useless on the line of code that crashed.  However, the visual studio debugger told me that SwapChain was nullptr.  So I put an error check on the previous line and it logged "-2005270527" for `D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 49 of Application.cpp, `while (HWindow != nullptr);` was waiting for `HWindow` to **become** `nullptr`.  But HWindow is initialized as `nullptr` and therefore the while loop would skip and try to initialize a window that hasn't been created yet.

That line now reads `while (HWindow == nullptr);`.  This means the loop runs until the window has been created, thereby blocking initialization of a window that doesn't exist.